# How do I delete nodes older than X days?

Tags: 7, nodes

Does anyone have a snippet for deleting nodes that are older than 1 day? I would like to run this on cron tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Auto Expire](http://drupal.org/project/auto_expire) module.

> This module allows site administrators to set expiration times for content types.
>
> End users creating content that has auto expiry set cannot control the expiry time. They could be allowed to renew the content for one or more cycles.
>
> Before a node is expired a warning message is sent to the user that created that node. If the user has the proper rights he can then extend the node.

Comment: This seems to be an abandoned project now?

Answer (score 4):

I had problems with D7 using Auto Expire, and ended up using HOOK_cron() in a custom module:

```
function mymodule_cron() {

// we only want to deal with messages (a content type)
$message_type = "message";

// grab all messages
$message_nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $message_type));
// set up the timestamp for the expiry
$message_search_date = strtotime("- 30 days"); // UNIX timestamp for 30 days ago

// now loop through messages, & if they are old, expire them
  foreach($message_nodes as $m) {

    $obj = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $m);

    // when was it last updated, & is it still published?
    $last_update = $obj->changed->value();
    $published = $obj->status->value();

    // if it's still published & it's not recent, then unpublish it
    if(($message_search_date > $last_update) && $published<>0) {
        $obj->status = 0;
        $obj->save();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you have one for articles? i am looking for ways to remove old articles 3 years ago

Comment: In the example, the content type is 'message', so if your content type's machine name is 'article', it should just be a question of changing - $message_type = "message"; - to - $message_type = "article";